# Can Electron do diagonal linear gradients?

Tags: javascript, electron, linear-gradients

I am new to development so I might be mistaken, but it seems like I'm not able to apply a diagonal gradient to the body in Electron.  This works perfectly fine:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #17A589, #117A65);
```

But whenever I try adding, say, bottom in front of left, it does not work.  I checked my syntax online and it seems right.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
what's weird is that on every page it is diferent, while using the same stylesheet...
here is the first page's version:
[First version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zG5x.png)
here is the
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMFqJ.png), and the third is the one that works properly, so I won't add any images for it.

Comment: works fine for me ```background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #17A589, #117A65);```

Comment: Electron's CSS should have the same capabilities as the corresponding version of Chrome.

Comment: well, i forgot to include an important part, what is does when I try to do a diagonal one is that it creates a horizontal weird fading ligne patern.